# MySQL - UNION over SELECT result

Tags: mysql, select, union

In my table is plenty of rows, I prepare test_result_table:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, DATA
  FROM table
  WHERE DATA = "A" OR DATA = "B" OR DATA = "C"
) AS test_result_table
```

How I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 AS RESULT, ID 
        FROM test_result_table
        WHERE DATA = "A"
      UNION  
        SELECT 2 AS RESULT, ID 
        FROM test_result_table
        WHERE DATA = "B"
      UNION
        SELECT 3 AS RESULT, ID 
        FROM test_result_table
        WHERE DATA = "C"
    ) AS result_id
ORDER BY RESULT
```

I know to do with temp table, is any better (faster) solution?

I expect (x = some ID):

```
RESULT |ID
1      |x
1      |x 
2      |x
2      |x
3      |x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same results by using the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which will return the value of the column `RESULT`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    FIND_IN_SET(DATA, 'A,B,C') AS RESULT, 
    ID
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE t.RESULT > 0
ORDER BY t.RESULT
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fe8b8dd758494052ed591842a739919c).
I can't tell about it's efficiency, but it surely is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for idea... it is 2time faster than my UNION over my 2mio rows